# Thread Safety, Application Design

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, thread-safety, console-application

I have a Console app that loops through a queue and processes each record in a datatable.   Each process is long and time-consuming (connecting to a remote website, downloading files, reading them and adding them to the database).  I'm trying to implement threading for speed's sake but am having cross-threading issues.  (The job takes 8 hours or so to run and the cross-threading doesn't start happening until a couple hours into the run.)

I'm trying to figure out how to make my code thread safe.  I don't update or rely on any non-local variables, and I don't need to return anything.  I've tried locking which works but defeats the purpose of the multiple threads.  What other things should I be looking for?

```
Module Module1

Dim iThread As Integer
Dim manualEvents(4) As ManualResetEvent
Private lockObject As New Object()

Sub Main()
    ' some prep work

    For i = 0 To 4
        manualEvents(i) = New ManualResetEvent(False)
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AddressOf DoOne)
    Next

    For Each handle As WaitHandle In manualEvents
        handle.WaitOne()
    Next

    ' some cleaning
End Sub


Private Sub DoOne()
    If QueryQueue Then
        DoOne()
    Else
        manualEvents(iThread).Set()
        iThread = iThread + 1
    End If
End Sub


Public Function QueryQueue() As Boolean

    Dim dt As DataTable = GetData()
    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        With dt
            Dim Variable1 As String = .Rows(0).Item("Variable1")
            Dim Variable2 As String = .Rows(0).Item("Variable2")
            Dim Variable3 As Integer = .Rows(0).Item("Variable3")
            ProcessRecord(Variable1, Variable2, Variable3)
        End With
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If

End Function

Public Sub ProcessRecord(ByVal Variable1 As String, ByVal Variable2 As String, ByVal Variable3 As Integer)
    AnotherMethod(Variable1, Variable2, Variable3)
End Sub

Public Sub AnotherMethod(ByVal Variable1 As String, ByVal Variable2 As String, ByVal Variable3 As Integer)
    AnotherMethod2(Variable1, Variable2, Variable3)
End Sub

Public Sub AnotherMethod2(ByVal Variable1 As String, ByVal Variable2 As String, ByVal Variable3 As Integer)
    AnotherMethod3(Variable1, Variable2, Variable3)
End Sub

' ... etc.

End Module
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ordering of thread using ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833673/ordering-of-thread-using-threadpool-queueuserworkitem)

Comment: @7lan: The accepted answer to the question I linked to should provide you with a pretty complete implementation of what you're looking for. If you want more information or a more thorough writeup of what's going on, I can give you a link to the blog post I wrote on the subject.

Comment: Thanks Adam, I'll look at that other question.  I would be very interested in seeing your blog post as well.

Comment: @7lan: http://idleide.wordpress.com/2009/12/03/processqueue/

Answer (score 0):

`iThread = iThread + 1` is not thread safe.
You should call `Interlocked.Increment` instead.

If you're using .Net 4.0, you should use the new `Task` API instead of the ThreadPool; you can then call `Task.WaitAll`.